# how to remove a dom element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

i have a link and i would like to remove it using javascript

here's what i have so far

```
<a href="">test</a>

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (a[i].innerText === 'test') {
        a.remove();
    }
}
```

this will fail.

Comment: +1 for non-jQuery -- it's good to see someone still learning the principles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it this way. `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` returns live collection, so loop in reverse order. So try

```
var aColl = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = aColl.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { //loop from reverese order, so that removed item doesn't affect 
    var thisNode = aColl[i];
    if (thisNode.innerHTML === 'test') {
        thisNode.parentNode.removeChild(thisNode );
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRL9E/)**

If you do it `for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {` then you end up removing only half of it, since each removal will update the NodeCollection in a and you will end up losing the elements at higher index and your check will fail.

Comment: @Patrioticcow See the explanation on why you shouldn't do the other way around.